# can not open ics file on iPhone

Tags: iphone, icalendar

I'm doing testing .ics file samples on my iPhone.

But when I open .ics file, same message keeps showing as belows:

`"This invitation data has been expired."`  (I'm not sure if this translation is correct...)

I can't even open other sample files. Just same messages are showed up.

Here is the code of sample file.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:uid1@example.com
DTSTAMP:20160714T170000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=John Doe:MAILTO:john.doe@example.com
DTSTART:20160714T170000Z
DTEND:20160715T035959Z
SUMMARY:Bastille Day Party
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Any suggestions?

I hope you understand my Enligsh. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The DTSTAMP is in the future which I believe should be the date that the ICS entry was created (and therefore should be in the past).

I rely heavily on sending ICS files to my iPhone and I always send them to an email address and open it from the Mail app on the iPhone. I tested this procedure with the example ICS from your questions and it worked fine for me.

What kind of calendar are you adding this event to. Is it added to a local, iCloud, Google or even some kind of subscribed calendar?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I changed the date of `DTSTAMP` like you said.(year 2016 -> year 2014) And I tried to open `ics` file again. But the same message is still showing up.

Comment: Hi @Chris. I refined my answer. I tried your example and it works for me. How are you trying to open this file and does opening the ICS in the Mail app work for you to?

Comment: I tried to open this file in the same way as you did. I want to apply a schedule of this file to my iPhone calendar. It is opening fine, but the message has showed up at the bottom.

Comment: What kind of calendar are you adding this event to. Is it added to a local, iCloud, Google or even some kind of subscribed calendar?